# Measure for accumulated variation

Tags: powerbi, dax

[PBIX file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10CwOkDeUzVSMSDaPj2TOHXn6KAdnoYFv/view?usp=sharing)

I want the accumulated percent variation of values from the oldest date. As an example, category 3 raised 36% (89 to 121) from February to March and 88% (89 to 167) from February to April.

[image]

I want to build a line graphic of accumulated percent variations which this one is not:

[image]

But I'm struggling  to understand contexts and these are the wrong values I get using my measures:

```
Oldest = min([d])
Variation = (sum(T[v]) / sumx(filter(T; T[d] = [Oldest]); [v]) - 1) * 100
```

[image]

What am I missing? Please ask for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see is that your `Oldest` measure needs to be the min over all selected dates rather than the min in the local filter context (which includes the date context generated by `d` on the x-axis).

I think you want something like this:

```
ChangeSinceStart =
VAR Oldest = CALCULATE ( MIN ( T[d] ), ALLSELECTED ( T[d] ) )
VAR StartValue = CALCULATE ( SUM ( T[v] ), T[d] = Oldest )
RETURN
    SUM ( T[v] ) / StartValue - 1
```

Multiply by 100 or format as %, whichever as you prefer.